# Reload doesn't return Achievements dropdown to the top

Tags: bug, status-declined, top-bar

Open the Achievements dropdown. Scroll down within it. Reload the page. Open the Achievements dropdown. Notice how it's still scrolled down. Be mystified.

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0

Comment: Norepro on Chrome. And here I was hoping for some mysticism.

Comment: `status-repro` on Firefox 25.0 but non-repro on Chrome.

Comment: No repro (IE 10; Win RT).

Comment: I think that's just a Firefox feature. If you do a hard refresh, the scroll position will be at the top again.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a firefox specific "feature."  If you don't like it though, please file a bug report on their forums...this isn't an issue with our simple `overflow: scroll` element, but a basic browser behavior.  I see cases where that behavior would be useful, but this isn't necessarily one of them.